# Tables in divs overlapping (IE) (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, html-table

I currently have two divs that are floating correctly, but the content within the divs are overlapping each other. This only happens in IE.

[tables overlapping in floated divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYKsT.png)

Here is my css code:

```
body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.tableparent {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px; 
    left:50px;
    width:650px;
    height:650px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tableleft {
    width:325px;
    height:650px;
    float:left;
}

.tableright {
    width:325px;
    float:right;
}

.button {
    margin-top:535px;
}
```

Here is my .aspx:

```
<div class="tableparent">
    <div class="tableleft">
        <div class="table"> 
            <table id="tblModelRank" runat="server" align="right" cellpadding="5" >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="tblModelRank" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankIDMR" runat="server" Text="Model Rank ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankIDMR" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankMR" runat="server" Text="Model Rank" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankMR" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelIDMR" runat="server" Text="Model ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelIDMR" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                   <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentMR" runat="server" Text="Comment" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentMR" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table">
            <table id="tblBLS_ModelRank" runat="server" align="right" cellpadding="5" >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="tblBLS_ModelRank" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankIDBLS" runat="server" Text="Model Rank ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankIDBLS" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankBLS" runat="server" Text="Model Rank" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankBLS" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelIDBLS" runat="server" Text="Model ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelIDBLS" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentBLS" runat="server" Text="Comment" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBLS" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table">
            <table id="tblModelAlias" runat="server" align="right" cellpadding="5" >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="tblModelAlias" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelIDMA" runat="server" Text="Model ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelIDMA" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelAliasMA" runat="server" Text="Model Alias" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelAliasMA" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentMA" runat="server" Text="Comment" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentMA" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tableright">
        <div class="table"> 
            <table id="tblModelRankSonar" runat="server" align="right" cellpadding="5" >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="tblModelRank (SONAR)" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankIDMR_S" runat="server" Text="Model Rank ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankIDMR_S" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelRankMR_S" runat="server" Text="Model Rank" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelRankMR_S" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelIDMR_S" runat="server" Text="Model ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelIDMR_S" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>        
                   <td style="text-align: right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentMR_S" runat="server" Text="Comment" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentMR_S" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I've tried a lot of suggestions from other similar questions to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't do much without the HTML.

Comment: I added my code. I think it may have to do with my version of IE - I have 11.0.44 and someone else tried it with a higher version and it was resolved.

Comment: tested all your code in an aspx webform and worked fine in IE 11.0.96 but I don't have version 11.0.44. I just added a couple of missing close div tags by the end of html code, but they were not a problem for my IE.